# increase images sizes loads in carousel view android

Tags: android, image, carousel

I created app to display images from internet in carousel view. I loaded images into carousel view using imageview. just like following way.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.showsmain, null);

        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       // RelativeLayout rlayout=(RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.rlayouts);
       image.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
        orgWidth = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        orgHeight = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        imageLoader.getDimension(widthScreen, heightScreen);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                widthScreen, heightScreen/3);
        params.width=widthScreen;
            image.setLayoutParams(params);
            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            //rlayout.addView(image);
        return vi;
    }
```

and my carousel layout xml file is,

```
<com.touchmenotapps.carousel.simple.HorizontalCarouselLayout
        android:id="@+id/carousel_layout_event"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/carousel_layout" >

    </com.touchmenotapps.carousel.simple.HorizontalCarouselLayout>
```

then image show as following way in carousel,

![enter image description here][1]

Here i want to increase the image width & height. It means one images must load fill with in the screen

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.showimage, null);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        //LinearLayout rlayout=(LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.layout);
       image.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
        orgWidth = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        orgHeight = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        imageLoader.getDimension(widthScreen, heightScreen);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                widthScreen,heightScreen/3);
        params.width=widthScreen/2;
            image.setLayoutParams(params);
            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            //rlayout.addView(image);
        return vi;
    }
```

this way I add the imageview into carousel view.

how to do that. I asked question similer this one. But i didn't get answer. pls help me someone. pls.....

my imageview xml layout file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/rlayouts">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a Horizontal oriented Linear layout inside a Horizontal ScrollView then you should add ImageViews with FillParent Height and Width in this Linear layout.

It would be great if you elaborate your question a bit more.

Comment: Thank suresh. I followed your answer. but I got runtime error. I edited my question. there you can see how I add the imageview into carousel view. So can you give me the answer after looking at it...

Comment: This work. but I don't want to use scrollview. Instead of that I want to load the full image into my screen without crop.

Comment: What is the runtime error. can you paste this? and in order to answer your code i need to check your whole XML file and definition of HorizontalCarouselLayout.

Comment: ok..Now not coming run time error. It was my error. I gave imageview xml layout full code in my question. I don't want to use scroll view. Instead  of that I want to load full image in my carousel view without croping. Also I want to increase image width the images loading in carousel view..

Comment: Why you set android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"